# How does this snippet give the output as 7?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, output, do-while

```
public class YourClassNameHere {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
          int i = 1;
          do 
          while(i++ <= 2);
          while(i++ <= 4);
          System.out.println(i);

        }
    }
```

How loops and post-increment  are working in this program.

Comment: Get a pencil and paper, work through by hand.

Comment: use a debugger and you will see

Comment: First hint: expand each of the loops to have a body with braces, and then you can add logging within the body...

Comment: What do you expect it to give as the output?

Comment: ChiefTwoPencils I only want to know the flow of the program.How it is giving 7 as output, not any preferred output.

Comment: Andy Turner and Jens, Thanks but I have posted this question after trying my best, using a pen,paper, and online code visualizer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look this it working nested while loop.

```
 int i = 1;
      do {
      System.out.println("start"+i);
      while(i++ <= 2)System.out.println("inner while loop "+i);
      }
      while(i++ <= 4)System.out.println("outer while loop"+i);
      System.out.println("final ans"+i);
```

Comment: When i get incremented to 4 then both while loop condition gets false so it should print i = 5,but not.How i gets incremented to 6 & 7.

Comment: when i variable value =4  because of <= 4 then do while loop condition gets true n post increment call (i++) mins i= 5 then  while (i++<=2) condition get false and post increment i++ call  mins i=6 and then do while loop condition get false and post increment call mins i=7 . that's why it give out put 7.

Answer (score 2):

As the halim said you have nested loop. Put some more System.out.println in the code and look at the result.

Example:

```
 int i = 1;      
 do
 {
    System.out.println("i = " + i + " on position: outer loop start");
    while (i++ <= 2)
    {
      System.out.println("i = " + i + " on position: inner while loop");          
    }
    System.out.println("i = " + i + " on position: outer while loop");
  } while (i++ <= 4);

  System.out.println("i = " + i + " on position: final result");
```

After you see the result you will see how the "i" variable is increment from 1 to 7 and on whitch position it is happening. You need to know that in condition i++ <= 2 if input "i" is 2 the first thing will be 2<=2 (true) and after that "i" will get it increment value of 3. In next pass you will check 3<=4 (false) but because you have i++ it will still get his increment value of 4.
Run the above code and see where the increment is really happening.

Answer (score 1):

To simply put, you're not using enough brackets. I suggest to use brackets in all ´do´, ´if´, etc. otherwise you may get an unexpected result (like in here?). Is there any specific output you want to see or just why in this case you get 7?

Regardless of the answer, halim's solution is what I'm talking about:

```
do {
while (i++ <= 2);
}
// remaining code in here
```